# nodejs subprocess.stdout.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuetify.js

I need to load the result from exec by stream in nodejs/Vuetify.js:

nodejs :

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
_execPull(location){
    try{
        return child_process.exec('docker pull '+location);
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

vuetify.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";

export default {
    name: 'ds',
    data: function() {
    return {
        message:false
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    computed:{
    },
    components: {
    },
    methods: {
        responseReceved(response){
            this.message = '';
            if (typeof response !="string"){
                console.log(response);
                response.stdout.on('data',(chunk)=>{
                    this.message += chunk.toString('utf8');
                });
                response.stdout.on('end',(chunk)=>{
                    // do something;
                });
            }
        },
    },
    destroyed() {
    }
};
```

I want something like this, line by line asynchronously:

```
commit: Pulling from project

ffffffffffff: Already exists

ffffffffffff: Pulling fs layer

ffffffffffff: Waiting

ffffffffffff: Verifying Checksum
ffffffffffff: Download complete

ffffffffffff: Pull complete

Digest: sha256:ffffffffffff...

Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.git.fr/project:commit
```

but this code return :
TypeError: response.stdout.on is not a function

and console.log(response.stdout) return an object:

```
Socket {
  connecting: false,
  _hadError: false,
  _handle:
   Pipe {
     onread: [Function: onStreamRead],
     reading: true,
     [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular] },
  _parent: null,
  _host: null,
  _readableState:
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: true,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: true,
     sync: false,
     needReadable: true,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: true,
     paused: false,
     emitClose: false,
     destroyed: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder:
      StringDecoder {
        encoding: 'utf8',
        [Symbol(kNativeDecoder)]: <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 01> },
     encoding: 'utf8' },
  readable: true,
  _events:
   [Object: null prototype] {
     end: [Function: onReadableStreamEnd],
     close: [Function],
     data: [Function: onChildStdout] },
  _eventsCount: 3,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _writableState:
   WritableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     finalCalled: false,
     needDrain: false,
     ending: false,
     ended: false,
     finished: false,
     destroyed: false,
     decodeStrings: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     length: 0,
     writing: false,
     corked: 0,
     sync: true,
     bufferProcessing: false,
     onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
     writecb: null,
     writelen: 0,
     bufferedRequest: null,
     lastBufferedRequest: null,
     pendingcb: 0,
     prefinished: false,
     errorEmitted: false,
     emitClose: false,
     bufferedRequestCount: 0,
     corkedRequestsFree:
      { next: null,
        entry: null,
        finish: [Function: bound onCorkedFinish] } },
  writable: false,
  allowHalfOpen: false,
  _sockname: null,
  _pendingData: null,
  _pendingEncoding: '',
  server: null,
  _server: null,
  [Symbol(asyncId)]: 3830,
  [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
  [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
  [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
  [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 }
```

if I print in console i don't have any problems

nodejs :

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
_execPull(location){
    try{
        let pull = child_process.exec('docker pull '+location);
        pull.stdout.on('data',(chunk)=>{
            this.message += chunk.toString('utf8');
        });
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I find that socker.io couldn't send stream and I found an alternative to send stream : socket.io-stream 
https://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#Future-innovation